# Filtering using a cached jQuery object

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given this html:

```
<ul>
  <li id="1">First</li>
  <li id="2">Second</li>
  <li id="3">Third</li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​
```

And this jQuery:

```
var $first = $('li').eq(0),
    $second = $('li').eq(1),
    $third = $('li').eq(2);

$second.next($first).css('background-color','red');
```

Why is the third li element given the background colour of red? I expected that using the cached jQuery object ($first) as a filter would mean nothing would be found.

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rqw3F/1/

Thanks.

Comment: $second.css('background-color','red');??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) only takes a selector *string* as argument, so your argument is ignored and is effectively the same as:

```
$second.next().css('background-color','red');
```

Relevant part from [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L211) where non selector string filters are ignored:

```
    if ( selector && typeof selector === "string" ) {
        ret = jQuery.filter( selector, ret );
    }
```

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Seems so obvious now I look at the api page. Thanks for showing the source too.